Strange behavior of CInt function: throws System.OverflowException
The maximum value for the Integer data type is 2'147'483'647.
When I run this code:
Dim t As Integer = 4094
Dim sz as Integer
sz = CInt((t / 2) * 1024 * 1024)
sz = CInt(t * 1024 * 1024 / 2)

line 3 executes well, but line 4 throws this:

System.OverflowException: 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

I get this despite the fact the arithmetic expression results in the same value for both cases: 2'146'435'072, which is less than the maximum value for the Integer data type.
It appears that the compiler has decided that all intermediate results of the arithmetic expression inside of the CInt function must be of Integer data type too, and hence they must not exceed the maximum value for the Integer data type. Weird, but Ok.
Now if I run this code:
Dim t As Integer = 4094 * 2
Dim sz As Integer
sz = CInt(((t / 2) * 1024 * 1024) / 2)

the code executes without an error, despite the fact that an intermediate result of the expression inside of the CInt function exceeds the maximum value for the Integer data type.
Also this code executes without an error:
Dim ln As Long = CLng(1024 ^ 5)
Dim n As Integer = CInt((ln + 1) / (1024 ^ 2))

Apparently, in the last two examples the compiler decides that it's Ok if an intermediate result of the arithmetic expression inside of the CInt function exceeds the maximum value for the Integer data type.
So when using the CInt function we must check not only that the final result of an arithmetic expression is withing the Integer data type range, but also we must make sure that all intermediate results of the arithmetic expression are withing the range of some other data type. Sometimes it is Integer, sometimes it is not.
What rules are applied here when the compiler makes the decision what is the acceptable range for the intermediate results of an arithmetic expression?

Btw., you don't need the CInt() if you perform an integer division \ instead of the real division /

sz = CInt(t * 1024L * 1024 / 2)

I figured it out. Apparently, the problem is not with CInt function but with how arithmetic expressions are evaluated in VB.NET.
For example, multiplication (*) does not change the result type: if both operands are Integer, then the result must also be Integer. If one operand is Integer and the other operand is Double, then the result will be Double. If one operand is Integer and the other operand is Long, then the result will be Long.
On the other hand, division (/) always produces a Double result, even if both operands are Integer and the result is a whole number.
Dim n As Integer = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 - 1
Console.WriteLine((n * 2).GetType.ToString) 'outputs "System.Int32"
Console.WriteLine((n * 3).GetType.ToString) 'throws "System.OverflowException"
Console.WriteLine((n * 3.0).GetType.ToString) 'outputs "System.Double"
Console.WriteLine((n / 2).GetType.ToString) 'outputs "System.Double"
Console.WriteLine((4 / 2).GetType.ToString) 'outputs "System.Double"
Dim i As Integer = n * 3 - n * 2 'throws "System.OverflowException"
Dim l As Long = n * 3 - n * 2 'throws "System.OverflowException"
Dim d As Double = n * 3 - n * 2 'throws "System.OverflowException"
Dim l As Long = 3
Console.WriteLine((n * l).GetType.ToString) 'outputs "System.Int64"


It's not just the result: it's each step along the way, Mr Anderson.
The maximum value of a signed integer is a little over 2 billion. To compute the result of the final line, the code multiplies 4096 (t) by 1024, twice, before dividing by two. The larger result for this expression needs to exist, at least briefly, for the division operation, and it's too big to fit in an integer. You may need a Long instead.
